# Jquery change() function not working

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two tables and I want to have change event on one table.
That is when I click on first table, I want to have some changes to the second table. But somehow below change function is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$("#history_table table:eq(0)").click(function(){
                    $("#history_table table:eq(1) thead tr th:nth-child(1)").html("New");
                }); 

$("#history_table table:eq(1) thead tr th:nth-child(1)").change(function() {
                      alert('Handler for .change() called.');
                });
```

Here history_table is a div tag id and it has two tables. click() function is working but I am expecting to see alert message as well, but this is not showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event/handler isn't for (or fired by default for) this, it's for an input style element changing data, for example a `<input>` or a `<select>`.  Instead, you'll want a custom event (or manually firing `change`...) here, for example:

```
$("#history_table table:eq(0)").click(function(){
  $("#history_table table:eq(1) thead tr th:nth-child(1)").html("New")
     .trigger('myEvent');
}); 

$("#history_table table:eq(1) thead tr th:nth-child(1)").bind('myEvent', function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, it works fine. But what If I want to have my second table to always listen to an event, that is instead of calling trigger from another function, automatically I want to display alert message when somebody changes second table values. Is there any way?

Comment: @goutham - Not a built-in cross-browser one nope...that'd be very expensive to monitor :)